# What is the purpose of the underscore after variable name and comma?

Tags: variables, lua

I found this Lua code:

```
function displayName(name)
  name, _ = name:gsub("{", "\\{")
  return name
end
```

and again:

```
function parsePath(path)
  if type(path) == "string" then path, _ = path:gsub("\\", "/") end
  return path
end
```

I understand what the code does.. what I don't understand is that , _ (comma underscore) between the variable name and the assignation part (=).. so this one `name, _ = name:gsub("{", "\\{")` and this one `..then path, _ = path:gsub("\\", "/")`

Can someone explain to me the meaning of that thing ?

Wouldn't be `name = name:gsub(....)`  or `..then path = path:gsub(...)` the same ?

So why the script is written this way ?

Comment: The use of underscore in this way to denote an unused variable that must be defined is a common [programming idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_idiom) across many programming languages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many programming languages `_` is used to denote unused variables.

This is also applicable to Lua. It is pure style convention. You won't find anything about it in the Lua manual.

luackeck, the most common static code analyzer for Lua will give you warnings for having unused variables in your code. It will ignore variables named `_` in that regard.

> Wouldn't be name = name:gsub(....) or ..then path = path:gsub(...) the
> same ?

In your examples this is actually not necessary.

The only reason to have `_` in `name, _ = name:gsub("{", "\\{")` would be to give a hint that this function actually returns two values. Usually you would leave the `_` away.

Whereas `_, numReplaced = name:gsub("{", "\\{")` would make sense if you're only interested in the second return value. You cannot get that without adding the first unused variable.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and explanation.

So do you confirm that in those 2 portions of code the comma/underscore is meaningless and can be removed ?

(mmm... maybe originally the function was different and returned more values .. and it's a left-over)

Comment: well unless you want to give a hint that `string.gsub` acutally has 2 return values of which you only use the first, using underscore is meaningless here. From the Lua manual: "Before the assignment, the list of values is adjusted to the length of the list of variables. If there are more values than needed, the excess values are thrown away." so if you only provide a single variable the list returned by a function is adjusted to 1 element.

Comment: Thank you again. Now I got the meaning of that portion of code. Since string.gsub returns 2 values .. (and we are interested only in the first) both syntax work the same. One is simpler and cleaner to read (without the comma-underscore), the other in more precise and gives an hint about how the called string function works.

Comment: well ideally you know what that function does, if not you check the reference and find out. I personally prefer to only use _ where it is necessary.

Comment: I totally agree with you: I prefer a cleaner and more readable code too.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert in Lua, but this pattern is used in other programming languages like Python. The underscore means "a variable that is not going to be used". If your function returns an array with two elements, then you need to do this, otherwise you are going to get the whole array.

Comment: Yes .. I learned about it.. for example using the underscore variable in a for loop when the value of the index is irrelevant.

What puzzled me is that being used in the code I posted, where it seems only having no purpose, 'cause it simply gets the same value than the real variable, the one returned..