# Use for loop to iterate over table without index

Tags: lua

I want to iterate over a table in Lua, and it works with a code like this (`tabline_length` and `tab.width` have been set before):

```lua
for index, tab in ipairs(tabs) do
    tabline_length = tabline_length + tab.width
end
```

What bothers me (and my editor) a bit, is that the `index` variable defined in the `for` loop is not used. Can't I iterate the `tabs` table without defining the `index`? I've tested the following code, but it did not work:

```lua
for tab in tabs do
    tabline_length = tabline_length + tab.width
end
```

Comment: `for _, value in pairs(tabs) do ... end`? `_` is commonly used to mark values that are not used.

Comment: @Aki Yeah, that works! Although it still seems a bit weird  If you add that as an answer I'd happily accept it 

Comment: [1.3 – Some Lexical Conventions](https://www.lua.org/pil/1.3.html) of Programming in Lua (first edition) briefly covers this idiom (`_`). See also: [*What is the purpose of the underscore after variable name and comma?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67488493/2505965)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first option is to simply use `_` by convention for unused variables (please only do this for local variables though, don't pollute the global variables with an `_` entry containing some garbage which won't be collected).

This convention is recognized by most Lua linters, most notably Luacheck. Your editor is probably using Luacheck under the hood.

Alternatively, you *could* implement your own iterator `ivalues` which keeps the iteration index "private" as upvalue of a returned iterator closure:

```lua
function ivalues(t)
    local i = 0
    return function()
        i = i + 1
        return t[i]
    end
end
```

this could then be used as

```lua
for tab in ivalues(tabs) do
    ...
end
```

writing a (most probably less efficient) iterator just to discard a variable would be silly though, which is why you'll usually find `for _, val in ipairs(vals)` instead; however, such an iterator comes in handy when you implement more iterator helpers such as `map` or `fold`; for example, given an iterator helper `sum` which sums over the elements of an iterator, you could simply do `sum(ivalues(nums))` to find the sum of the numbers in a table of numbers `nums`. Writing this in terms of `ipairs` would be more awkward; you'd probably fall back to writing an imperative solution.

Comment: Thank you! I was just wondering if there is a built-in variant handling that use case, but it sounds like there is not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using lua 5.2+ you can use the __pairs metatable:

```
local thing = setmetatable({
    a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = 3,
    d = 4,
    e = 5
}, {
__pairs = function(s)
    local first = next(s)
    return function(s, k)
        if k == nil then
        return first, s[first]
        end
        local next = next(s, k)
        if next == nil then
        return nil
        end
        return next, s[next]
    end, s, nil
    end
})

for v in pairs(thing) do
    print(v)
end
```

http://lua-users.org/wiki/GeneralizedPairsAndIpairs